# How to properly replace a pre-defined delimiter used multiple times in a row

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a column that saves plain text and uses a delimiter to replace the images (that are in base64) in the first table with a delimiter comprised of a few unique characters and the ID of the base64 table.

For example:

TableA

notesColumn

A picture is right here <##1##> and then here is some text and another picture <##2##> and here is the end

There can be multiple results returned per instance. Rows with 1 delimiter work correctly. The problem here is when I try and select the ones with multiple delimiters to display based on the overall page, it will show something like this where it is displayed as multiple rows.

A picture is right here data:image/png;base64... and then here is some text and another picture <##2##> and here is the end

A picture is right here <##1##> and then here is some text and another picture data:image/png;base64... and here is the end

My general query was

```
 SELECT REPLACE(A.notesColumn,'<##'+CAST(B.base64ID AS VARCHAR(25))+'##>', B.docImage) [noteText]
 FROM tableA A
    LEFT JOIN base64Table B ON A.ID = B.tableANote
 WHERE pageID = @pageID
```

How can I fix the issue where it is displayed as multiple results and instead just be 1 row, regardless of how many delimiters?

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) is a great place to start.

Comment: Please share with us the contents of tableB.

Comment: @donPablo If you're referencing the base64Table, the contents are

ID, tableAID (FK), docImage (VARCHAR(MAX))

Comment: No just listing the columns is useless. Nobody can query against that. We need to have the table definitions, sample data and desired output based on your sample data.

Comment: I suspect that this could be achieved by using the Quirk Update, but without further information, I can't confirm that.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by breaking up your original text into the constituent words using a string splitting function and then `join`ing where required into your `base64Table` to get the relevant replacement values and then recombining via either `FOR XML` or `STRING_AGG` depending on whether your SQL Server is pre or post 2017.

If you are using SQL Server 2016 or higher you can also use `STRING_SPLIT` and if not you can use the function at the end of this answer, which is my modified version of [Jeff Moden's](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/tally-oh-an-improved-sql-8k-%e2%80%9ccsv-splitter%e2%80%9d-function).

```
declare @b table(id int,p varchar(100));
insert into @b values(1,'THIS IS PICTURE 1'),(2,'THIS IS PICTURE 2'),(3,'THIS IS PICTURE 3');

declare @t table(v varchar(500));
insert into @t values('A picture is right here <##1##> and then here is some text and another picture <##2##> and here is the end'),('Another picture is here <##1##> and yet more text and another picture <##2##> and here is the end');

select t.v as Original
      ,stuff((select ' ' + isnull(b.p,s.Item)
              from dbo.fn_StringSplit4k(t.v,' ',null) as s
                  left join @b as b
                    on left(s.Item,3) = '<##'
                        and cast(substring(s.Item,4,1) as int) = b.id
              order by s.rn
              for xml path('')
              ),1,1,'') as Replaced
from @t as t;
```

## Output

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                  Original                                                  |                                                            Replaced                                                            |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| A picture is right here <##1##> and then here is some text and another picture <##2##> and here is the end | A picture is right here THIS IS PICTURE 1 and then here is some text and another picture THIS IS PICTURE 2 and here is the end |
| Another picture is here <##1##> and yet more text and another picture <##2##> and here is the end          | Another picture is here THIS IS PICTURE 1 and yet more text and another picture THIS IS PICTURE 2 and here is the end          |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

---

## Roll your own String Split

```
create function dbo.fn_StringSplit4k
(
     @str nvarchar(4000) = ' '              -- String to split.
    ,@delimiter as nvarchar(1) = ','        -- Delimiting value to split on.
    ,@num as int = null                     -- Which value to return.
)
returns table
as
return
                    -- Start tally table with 10 rows.
    with n(n)   as (select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1)

                    -- Select the same number of rows as characters in @str as incremental row numbers.
                    -- Cross joins increase exponentially to a max possible 10,000 rows to cover largest @str length.
        ,t(t)   as (select top (select len(isnull(@str,'')) a) row_number() over (order by (select null)) from n n1,n n2,n n3,n n4)

                    -- Return the position of every value that follows the specified delimiter.
        ,s(s)   as (select 1 union all select t+1 from t where substring(isnull(@str,''),t,1) = @delimiter)

                    -- Return the start and length of every value, to use in the SUBSTRING function.
                    -- ISNULL/NULLIF combo handles the last value where there is no delimiter at the end of the string.
        ,l(s,l) as (select s,isnull(nullif(charindex(@delimiter,isnull(@str,''),s),0)-s,4000) from s)

    select rn
          ,item
    from(select row_number() over(order by s) as rn
                ,substring(@str,s,l) as item
        from l
        ) a
    where rn = @num
        or @num is null;
```

---

Looking at your question again, you may have need for a string splitter that can handle more than 4000 characters.  If that is the case, you can use this one instead, though it may well perform worse on smaller strings than the 4k version:

```
create function dbo.fn_StringSplitMax
(
    @str nvarchar(max) = ' '                -- String to split.
    ,@delimiter as nvarchar(max) = ','      -- Delimiting value to split on.
    ,@num as int = null                     -- Which value to return.
)
returns table
as
return
    with s as
    (       -- Convert the string to an XML value, replacing the delimiter with XML tags
        select convert(xml,'<x>' + replace((select @str for xml path('')),@delimiter,'</x><x>') + '</x>').query('.') as s
    )
    select rn
          ,item     -- Select the values from the generated XML value by CROSS APPLYing to the XML nodes
    from(select row_number() over (order by (select null)) as rn
              ,n.x.value('.','nvarchar(max)') as item
        from s
              cross apply s.nodes('x') as n(x)
        ) a
    where rn = @num
        or @num is null;
```

Comment: Where is your function fn_StringSplit4k?

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the rare moments, where a *quirky update* can help a lot:

(Credits to @iamdave, used parts of his mcve)

```
CREATE TABLE B(id int,p varchar(100));
insert into B values(1,'THIS IS PICTURE 1'),(2,'THIS IS PICTURE 2'),(3,'THIS IS PICTURE 3');
GO

CREATE TABLE A(v varchar(500));
insert into A values('A picture is right here <##1##> and then here is some text and another picture <##2##> and here is the end')
                   ,('Another picture is here <##1##> and yet more text and another picture <##2##> and here is the end')
                   ,('Another example with a picutre <##2##> here and one more here <##3##>');
GO
```

--The magic happens here:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.MultipleImageReplace(@input VARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX) AS
BEGIN
    SELECT @input = REPLACE(@input,CONCAT('<##',B.id,'##>'),B.p)    FROM B;
    RETURN @input;
END
GO
```

--this is how you call it:

```
SELECT *
      ,dbo.MultipleImageReplace(A.v) AS ReplacedText
FROM A;
GO
```

--Clean-Up: Careful with real data!

```
DROP FUNCTION dbo.MultipleImageReplace;
GO
DROP TABLE B;
GO
DROP TABLE A;
```

the result

```
A picture is right here THIS IS PICTURE 1 and then here is some text and another picture THIS IS PICTURE 2 and here is the end
Another picture is here THIS IS PICTURE 1 and yet more text and another picture THIS IS PICTURE 2 and here is the end
Another example with a picutre THIS IS PICTURE 2 here and one more here THIS IS PICTURE 3
```

Some background to the *magic quirky update*:

The function uses `@input=Modify(@input)`. This will lead to a *row-by-row* action, where each row of table `B` will modify the content of `@input` and re-assign it to the variable. So the next row will work with the modified content and so on.

There are some severe draw backs with this approach, nothing recommended in general. But hin this case, where sorting does not matter, you can give it a go.

Answer (score 0):

I place this as a second answer as the approach is entirely different then the other one and I do not want to mix this up.

You can use `XQuery` and its very mighty abilities to deal with generic data.

The test-scenario:

```
CREATE TABLE B(id int,p varchar(100));
insert into B values(1,'THIS IS PICTURE 1'),(2,'THIS IS PICTURE 2'),(3,'THIS IS PICTURE 3');
GO

CREATE TABLE A(v varchar(500));
insert into A values('A picture is right here <##1##> and then here is some text and another picture <##2##> and here is the end')
                   ,('Another picture is here <##1##> and yet more text and another picture <##2##> and here is the end')
                   ,('Another example with a picutre <##2##> here and one more here <##3##>');
GO
```

--The CTE will use some replacements to transform your strings to XML

```
WITH Casted AS
(
    SELECT *
          ,CAST('<root>
                 <row>
                   <text>' + REPLACE(REPLACE(A.v,'<##','</text><img index="'),'##>','"/><text>') + '</text>
                 </row>
                 <images>' +

                 --and we will include the pictures to be part of the XML
                 --this will make it easier to use them in the XQuery
                 --You might use two CTEs to include just the pictures needed
                 (
                    SELECT *
                    FROM B
                    FOR XML PATH('img')
                 ) + 
                 '</images>
                 </root>
                 ' AS XML) AS CastedToXml
    FROM A
)
--We use a simple "for .. in .." loop to travers down the nodes and return their content "as-is" or replaced by the corresponding image
SELECT CastedToXml.query('for $nd in /root/row/*
                          return
                          if(local-name($nd)="img") then 
                              /root/images/img[id=$nd/@index]/p/text()
                          else 
                              $nd/text()
                         ').value('.','nvarchar(max)')
FROM Casted
GO
```

--Clean-Up: Carefull with real data!

```
DROP TABLE B;
GO
DROP TABLE A;
```

One transformed XML would look like this:

```
<root>
  <row>
    <text>Another example with a picutre </text>
    <img index="2" />
    <text> here and one more here </text>
    <img index="3" />
    <text />
  </row>
  <images>
    <img>
      <id>1</id>
      <p>THIS IS PICTURE 1</p>
    </img>
    <img>
      <id>2</id>
      <p>THIS IS PICTURE 2</p>
    </img>
    <img>
      <id>3</id>
      <p>THIS IS PICTURE 3</p>
    </img>
  </images>
</root>
```

And the result is

```
A picture is right here THIS IS PICTURE 1 and then here is some text and another picture THIS IS PICTURE 2 and here is the end
Another picture is here THIS IS PICTURE 1 and yet more text and another picture THIS IS PICTURE 2 and here is the end
Another example with a picutre THIS IS PICTURE 2 here and one more here THIS IS PICTURE 3
```